# Override nav bar back button click on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have form in xamarin.forms and I want to show a popup message when users click on the nav bar button if there are pending data to save. I found this [example](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/) but it doesn't not working on Xamarin.Forms 5.0

Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: this has been asked dozens of times - please search before posting.  https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+forms+prevent+back+navigation+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: further, consider that you might want to make the page a modal if you want to prevent them from navigating without saving

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on this you can refer to it.

First, I create a contentpage and set **CustomBackButtonAction**, **EnableBackButtonOverride** to add navigate method:

```
public partial class TestPage5 : ContentPage
    {public Action CustomBackButtonAction { get; set; }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(EnableBackButtonOverride),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TestPage5),
            false
            );
          public bool EnableBackButtonOverride {

            get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty, value); }
        }
        public TestPage5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EnableBackButtonOverride = true;
            CustomBackButtonAction = async () => { var result = await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Are you Sure?", "Yes", "No");
                if (result)
                { await Navigation.PopAsync(true); }     };
        }  
        }
```

Then create renderer on ios while override OnOptionsItemSelected on android:

**ios(create a new backbutton and override):**

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(TestPage5),typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace My_Forms_Test3.iOS
{
    public class MyRenderer:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            if (((TestPage5)Element).EnableBackButtonOverride)
            {
                SetButton();
            }
        }

           private void SetButton()
            {
            var backbuttonimg = UIImage.FromBundle("backarrow.png");
            backbuttonimg = backbuttonimg.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
            var backbutton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom)
            { HorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left,
            TitleEdgeInsets=new UIEdgeInsets(11.5f,15f,10f,0f),
            ImageEdgeInsets=new UIEdgeInsets(1f,8f,0f,0f)};
            backbutton.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
            backbutton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
            backbutton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.LightGray, UIControlState.Highlighted);
            backbutton.Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue", (nfloat)17);
            backbutton.SetImage(backbuttonimg, UIControlState.Normal);
            backbutton.SizeToFit();
            backbutton.TouchDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (((TestPage5)Element)?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
                {
                    ((TestPage5)Element)?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();

                }
            };
            backbutton.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 4,
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height);
            var buttoncontainer = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, backbutton.Frame.Width, backbutton.Frame.Height));
            buttoncontainer.AddSubview(backbutton);
            var fixspace = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace)
            { Width = -16f };
            var backbuttonitem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null) { CustomView = backbutton };
            NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = new[] { fixspace, backbuttonitem };
        }
    }
    }
```

**android:**

add following on main activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
 
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
 
            //important to trigger OnOptionItemSelected
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar
             = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

also in mainactivity.cs:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            // check if the current item id 
            // is equals to the back button id
            if (item.ItemId == 16908332) // xam forms nav bar back button id
            {
                // retrieve the current xamarin 
                // forms page instance
                var currentpage = (TestPage5)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.
                     MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
 
                // check if the page has subscribed to the custom back button event
                if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
                {
                    // invoke the Custom back button action
                    currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
                    // and disable the default back button action
                    return false;
                }
 
                // if its not subscribed then go ahead 
                // with the default back button action
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            else
            {
                // since its not the back button 
                //click, pass the event to the base
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
 
        //android Hardware back button event
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            // this is really not necessary, but in Android user has both Nav bar back button 
            // and physical back button, so its safe to cover the both events
 
            var currentpage = (BaseContentPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.
                MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
 
            if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
            {
                currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The SetSupportActionBar requires a AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolba not a Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar object

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full blog I have written which handles the same,

**Android:**

I have used **NavigationPage Renderer** to achieve this functionality in android

[Android Implementtion](https://dineshphalwadiya1995.medium.com/?p=6f47cc30e288)

**iOS:**

I have used **Page Renderer** to achieve this functionality in iOS

```
public class CustomPageRenderer:PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        if (Element != null && Element is BasePage basePage && basePage.BindingContext != null &&
            basePage.BindingContext is BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
        {
            SetCustomBackButton(baseViewModel);
        }
    }
    private void SetCustomBackButton(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
    {
        UIButton btn = new UIButton();
        btn.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 50, 40);
        btn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        btn.TouchDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Whatever your custom back button click handling
            baseViewModel.BackPressedAction?.Invoke(false);
        };
        //var views = NavigationController?.NavigationBar.Subviews;
        NavigationController?.NavigationBar.AddSubview(btn);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Do create **BackPressedAction** Action in your base view model to capture the back press event

Comment: The android code is using a Prism based project. I can't migrate all code to a prism structure at this point.

Comment: Hi, @EloyMillanes if you closely look into the code you will find there is nothing many dependencies on prism as we are using renderers. You just have to change the code as per your structure & it will be working fine too.